# Sql error-int is incompatible with date

Tags: mysql

```
create table TCS_Employee 
(
Emp_name varchar(30),
Emp_id int identity(1,1)primary key,
Emp_Sal money not null,
Joining_data date,
login_date datetime,
Domain varchar not null
)

insert into TCS_Employee 
(Emp_name,Emp_Sal,Joining_data,login_date,domain) values
('Varsha',50000,2015-01-05,GETDATE(),'retail')
```

please help in resolving the below error

> error-Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Comment: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: even after using '2015-01-05' I am getting the error Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You most likely need to set the length of the `Domain` column too.

Answer (score 1):

The date needs to be in quotes, otherwise it is treated as an integer.

Change `2015-01-05` to `'2015-01-05'`

Also, you should set to length of the `domain` column (like `Domain varchar(50) not null` or w/e length is appropriate for your needs).

Omitting the length is a bad practice and can give unexpected results as different databases default to different lengths and for some the length is mandatory (I believe it is for MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

`2015-01-05` is actually performing the arithmetic operation of subtraction and hence, the result is an int, not a valid date format.

use : `'2015-01-05'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the quotes:

```
 INSERT INTO TCS_Employee
    (Emp_name, Emp_Sal, Joining_data, login_date, domain)
    VALUES
    ('Varsha',50000,'2015-01-05',GETDATE(),'retail');
```